# OpenGL + Optimizing drawing particle objects for cloth simulation

Tags: c++, opengl

I am creating a cloth simulation for the first time. I have created a class for point masses called 'Particle' that stores all of the important information such as its current and previous positions, the forces acting on it, normal, mass.... etc.

I want to draw these particles for which I only need the currentPosition which is the first of many parameters in the class (see below). From my meagre experience it seems the way to draw these particles would be to send the entire array of Particle objects down to the GPU then give it the stride using Glvertexattribpointer(). It seems like there is a considerable amount of unnecessary information being passed to the GPU however when doing this. I have considered creating a new array and filling it with only the position data every iteration of the draw call to send down but this method however seems like a large overhead of both memory and CPU power.

How does the penalty caused by sending unneeded data to the GPU compare to creating a vertex only array? Granted, my particle class isn't huge but I figure cloths require a large number of particles so the redundant data could add up fast. Is there an alternative to both of these methods I am unaware of?

```
#ifndef PARTICLE_HPP
#define PARTICLE_HPP
#pragma once
#include <atlas/utils/Geometry.hpp>
class Particle {
public:
    Particle(glm::vec3 pos);
    ~Particle();

    void addForce(glm::vec3 force);
    void updateGeometry(atlas::utils::Time const& t, GLfloat DAMPING);
    void makeMoveable();
    void makeStationary();
    void resetAcceleration();
    void setPosition(glm::vec3 newPos);
    void offSetPosition(glm::vec3 newPos);
    void addToSumOfSpringForces(glm::vec3 force);
    void setWind(glm::vec3 wind_);
    void resetNormal();
    void addToNormal(glm::vec3 V);
    glm::vec3 getCurrentPosition();
private:    
    glm::vec3 currentPosition, previousPosition, acceleration, totalSpringForces, gravity, wind, velocity, mNormal;
    GLfloat mass, dragCoefficient;
    bool stationary;
};
#endif // !PARTICLE_HPP
```

Comment: Array of Structures (AoS) vs Structure of Arrays (SoA).

Answer (score 0):

At some point, you need to allocate server GPU memory to store the particle data - whether it's just the positions, or the positions along with all the other data. Whatever vertex buffering method you use (client buffers, VBOs, VAOs, etc), your data at some point needs to be copied from client memory into server memory (CPU to GPU). Thus, if all you need is the `currentPosition` data within your shader drawing the particles, allocating the additional memory and copying it is wasteful and will never perform as well.

Alternatively, you could do your particle simulation on the GPU, and skip the transfer completely, which would likely be much more efficient assuming your have sufficient hardware and don't need CPU access to the particle data.